# Refreshing the content of the datatable to get new data from database

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I want to know how this can be done?
I am taking data from the database and through DataAdapter i am updating values in datatable.So now if any new data are entered into database how can i refresh or update the new data to the datatable?

Comment: If you have used the `DataTable`+`DataAdapter` to update the database, the `DataTable` already contains the new data. So no need to "refresh" it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think you have understood my question wrongly.Think that that datatable contains some data of a database.So if a new data are entered to that database then i want them to update or refresh in the datatable.

Comment: The easiest way it to fill the `DataTable`/`DataSet` again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok.That is simple. But is there any other method to do it?

Comment: A `DataTable` is an offline, in-memory representation of your data, so you have to refresh it manually.

Comment: Another approach is to use [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Have a look here: http://www.fantabooks.net/lib/O'Reilly%20-%20ADO%20NET%203%205%20Cookbook%202nd%20Edition%20Mar%202008/final/automatically_refreshing_a_datatable_whe.php

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to fill the `DataTable`/`DataSet` again. A `DataTable` is an offline, in-memory representation of your data, so it does not know when the underlying data has changed.

However, you can use the [`SqlDependency`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Have a look [here](http://www.fantabooks.net/lib/O%27Reilly%20-%20ADO%20NET%203%205%20Cookbook%202nd%20Edition%20Mar%202008/final/automatically_refreshing_a_datatable_whe.php).